# Start Multiple Chat heads via same service

Tags: android, android-studio, service, broadcastreceiver, material-design

i am developing application that captures incoming call detains 
Now,i have to launch floating chat view after each incoming call so in short i have to launch each separate floating chat view per each incoming call so how can i launch multiple chat view using same services?

Comment: anyone has suggestion pls